# Can't boot to Kali Linux

Tags: windows, kali-linux, grub2, dual-boot

I have installed the operating system successfully on my laptop that has Windows 8.1 pre-installed. (With [this guide](http://docs.kali.org/installation/dual-boot-kali-with-windows))

After restarting the computer, Windows 8.1 loaded instead of grub bootloader, so I have searched in Google and found a program called easyBCD. I followed [this](https://superuser.com/a/499652/397082) simple guide, but when I get to the screen where to choose between Windows and Kali Linux there is a problem:

I choose Kali Linux and then I get an error that "Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software..." message...

I wanted to load grub bootloader but I can't seem to make it work.

How can I load grub bootloader? And if I can't, how can I make my machine to load Kali Linux at all?

Comment: Does trying fixing the bootloader problem as described here: http://m.instructables.com/id/Dual-Boot-Ubuntu-and-Windows-8-UEFI/?ALLSTEPS work?

Comment: That doesn't seem to help me at all actually..

Answer (score -1):

Ok after whole day sitting on the computer (way before I opened this question), I found a solution, [this guide](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2015/01/14/how-to-dual-boot-kali-linux-1-0-9-and-windows-78-on-a-pc-with-uefi-firmware/) here is just great! way more updated then the official one and more reliable.